# PHP: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: php, macos

When running any PHP command on my OSX 10.10 laptop, I get the following:

```
jpowers$ php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but cannot fix this issue. I *think* it may have started when I upgraded to OSX 10.10.

Comment: well, does the library exist? Also, it might be time to upgrade your php installation. PHP 5.3 is no longer officially supported.

Comment: so remove/disable apc from your php setup...

Comment: What are you using? mamp? I'd suggest a reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a custom install of php on your mac. Maybe homebrew?

Stock OSX php doesn't try to load anything from /usr/local

```
$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
```

Check your environment and maybe upgrade your php / Cellar installation using whatever package management solution you picked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments in this thread, I realized that I had a custom install of PHP on my Mac. After a little more research, I identified that the busted version was indeed the custom install. Per @mbaur64's comment, I used Homebrew to uninstall my custom version (`sudo brew rm php56`), then I used Homebrew to reinstall it. That alone fixed the issue.

Thanks for the help everyone!